# Laravel 9 does not open pages

Tags: php, laravel

I've just installed Laravel 9 with PHP version 8.1.3 but when I run the development server, the page does not open, it just keeps loading forever. No errors, nothing.

I never had any problems with Laravel 8 or older versions and I don't know what could cause this issue.

Comment: did you run `npm install & npm run dev`?

Comment: no, but I'll try now.

Comment: still same issue...

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console or `cmd` that run `php artisan serve`?

Comment: when you run php artisan serve, what's the message you get in response?

Comment: there are no erros in Chrome console, but just saw in the console of php artisan serve it says php v7.4.9. Looks like it's not using the latest php version.

Comment: could you add screenshot of your cmd after running `php artisan serve`

Comment: when you run `php artisan serve` you should get something like this : ` PHP 8.1.5 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started`, do you get this message? did you tried to access to webpage base on link in response to `serve`?

Comment: yeah, I get this message but it says PHP 7.4.9 Development server.... I think I need to update composer as well

Comment: ah, i've just saw you `php v7.4.9` comment. laravel 9 requirement is php 8 at least. so if you're running and you somehow getting `php v7.4.9` in response, then you should check the php version installed or modify `Path environment`.

Comment: this is not related to `composer`. how you installed `PHP 8`?

Comment: I've downloaded `PHP 8` using wamp addons and forgot to modify the Path environment. Just updated it and now everything is working fine. Thanks guys for your help !

Comment: @Yu_Jain good luck, I'll also recommend trying docker.

Comment: thanks, I've heard a lot about `Docker`. It's already in my `want-to-study list` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what you've said in response to `php artisan serve`, your problem should be related to your `PHP` version since `Laravel 9` required at least `PHP 8`.